# How can I determine what particle (∅, に or は) should I use with temporal nouns?

Tags: grammar, particles

I’m a bit confused with the choice of particle with temporal nouns. For example, which is the difference between the following sentences?

> 夏休旅行したいと思っています。

> 夏休に旅行したいと思っています。

> 夏休は旅行したいと思っています。

And another example:

> 午後晴れると言っていました。

> 午後に晴れると言っていました。

> 午後は晴れると言っていました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it may express different emphasis or when the action takes place, for example 明日に食べたい, I want to eat tomorrow vs 明日は食べたい, As for tomorrow, I want to eat it, which is more so introducing tomorrow as a new topic/in contrast of something else. Ex: 明日、早く起きますか？　はい、でも、明後日には10時前に起きません。in this case, both に and は mean as for on the day after tomorrow, which marks it as both when said action occurs and as a new topic.